# Microsoft Azure Concurrent task processing in Web jobs / functions

Tags: c#, azure, asynchronous, parallel-processing, azure-functions

We have a service which calls 3<sup>rd</sup> party (handles ***1 request criteria per call***) service to get data & responds in < 1 sec. Now we have a new requirement to get data for 100 different criteria. Since the 3<sup>rd</sup> party service handles only 1 request criteria. We are planning to create a wrapper service which makes 100 request (for each criteria) **concurrently in async manner** and aggregates the result. We are planning to deploy the service on cloud and we need to maintain the **same response time**. 
We have 2 approaches in mind:

1. Create a Web App and use TAP for parallel processing
2. Create Azure functions (Wrapper (Main function) and another to call 3<sup>rd</sup> party
   service) and do parallel processing

Can any one suggest the best patterns and practices to achieve this?

Comment: Have you communicated the need to request multiple criteria per call to the 3rd party? Maybe they could extend their service to accommodate you.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to a have a difficult time achieving the same latency for these new aggregated requests, as your response time becomes the worst of these 100 calls that you make.

The Web App solution would likely be more performant because it doesn't have the intermediate calls that your chained function solution would.

The bottleneck seems to be this 3rd party service - can you cache the criteria you need?

Comment: I would add that even though you can code your app to make 100 concurrent requests to the 3rd party service with Async programming, it's possible your App wont make 100 HTTP requests simultaniously. There may be a limit on the number of concurrent HTTP requests outgoing from your app on your server, or even from the same client in the 3rd party service.

Comment: We are planning to to deploy the service in azure as App service / service fabric with scaling. will it work?

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before, your greatest bottleneck there seems to be the third party response (unless you have a huge request body or something like that).
The big problem here is that, even if you manage to push out 100 request at once, you don't have any guarantee that they will be handled in a parallel manner, because perhaps the other end is backed up and it will queue your requests. Perhaps your requests could also issue lock-like actions that will hamper the scalability of the other end. You could also not benefit from the 3rd party cache since all requests are going in at once...
Another problem you might face is that, if everything is OK on the other side, there's a chance that you won't be able to handle all the requests responses heading back home at once, e.g., YOU will be clogged up! after all, it's not common to have 100 spare threads just laying around...

My suggestion is to use all weapons in your arsenal:

- Cache whatever you can avoiding unnecessary calls.
- Batch yours requests, try perhaps batches of 25 items.
- Try to work around your 1 sec timeframe by updating relevant info as they come along (yes, this is usually very well accepted by end-users)

Answer (score 0):

*I think the bottom line is that no matter which solution you choose, as good as it may be, is going to introduce overhead that you didn't have to worry about before.*

That being said, I've had decent success using TAP on a single web server for similar projects (i.e. discovering cameras on a network).  I'm not sure you'll be able to stay under 1 second though given the new requirement of 100 calls.

The only other way I can think of completing this request with that kind of response time would be to have 100 "warm" cloud services running and ready to respond.  But that would most definitely be too expensive for what you're doing.

Azure Batch also comes to mind but I think that will have even more overhead.